# Prolog Free Days Code

Tags: prolog

I have a Question regarding my Task.
Task :

People have Days assigned to them. On these days they are free for work.

**Karl is free on Mo,Wed,Thu**

**Lukas is free on Tue,Wed,Thu,Fr**

**Jon is free on Mo,Wed,Sa**

**Alex is free on Thu,Fr,Sa**

**Max is free on Mo,Wed,Fr,Sa,Su**

I created the Knowledgebase for these assumptions :

```
free(Karl,Mo).

free(Karl,Wed).

free(Karl,Thu).

..

..

free(Max,Su).
```

4 Questions are asked :

1. Is Person X free on Day Y.
2. When are which Persons free together.
3. Which Persons are free 2/3/4 Days in a Row.
4. Who is free 3 Days in a Row.

Questions 1 is Easy.

```
?- free(X,Day).
```

Cant figure out the last 3.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: On 2-4 you'll need to write some code: predicates which describe the logic to meet the criteria. What have you tried? Also, you're going to have a problem with the way you show your facts now. In Prolog, variables start with a capital letter or `_`, and atoms start with lower case. `free(Karl, Mo)` has two variables. You either need to enclose them in single quotes (`free('Karl', 'Mo')`) or use lower case, `free(karl, mo)`) or use a mix (`free('Karl', mo)`).

Comment: I would also recommend changing your day style from wordy-atoms to integers, so that you don't have to define that tue follows mo, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

> free(susi,1).
>
> free(susi,3).
>
> free(susi,4).
>
> free(horst,2).
>
> free(horst,3).
>
> free(horst,4).
>
> free(horst,5).
>
> free(lars,1).
>
> free(lars,3).
>
> free(lars,6).
>
> free(hanna,4).
>
> free(hanna,5).
>
> free(hanna,6).
>
> free(fridolin,1).
>
> free(fridolin,3).
>
> free(fridolin,5).
>
> free(fridolin,6).
>
> free(fridolin,7).
>
> %free(X,Y).
>
> %together(X,Y,Z).
>
> together(Person1,Person2,When) :-
>   free(Person1,When),free(Person2,When),+ (Person1=Person2).

Okay i updated the knowledge base and managed to get the first and second task done.

Stuck on the third now :/

Comment: For the third and fourth tasks, your best bet is to create a predicate that behaves like this:

free_for_days(Person, Count), which finds a day a person is free on then calls free_from_day_for_days(Person, Day, Count), which identifies if they are free on the next Day, then recurses on to free_from_day_for_days(Person, Day + 1, Count - 1)

Comment: Bearing in mind that you will need to use NewCount is Count - 1, as you cannot do in-place arithmetic in prolog. The '-' will be pattern-matched if you use the signature I provided in pseudo-code

Comment: You may also want to use 0 instead of 7 in your day count, so that you can make use of modulo when calculating the next day